# No bay correct size when installing SSD with mounting bracket

Tags: ssd, desktop-computer, desktop-customization

I’ve purchased a refurbished Dell desktop and am trying to install an SSD as an additional drive. I have a 2.5” to 3.5” mounting kit, SATA cable and there’s already a spare power cable.

However, I can’t seem to find a place that the 3.5” bracket actually fits - there’s a bay underneath the hard drive and the spare power cable is hanging there ready for another drive.

The problem is the mounting bracket is just not wide enough to attach here. The hard drive itself is inside a plastic pinch-to-remove casing - perhaps I need one of these to fit the drive inside the mounting bracket?

There’s also a spare bay underneath the DVD drive and another, smaller one underneath that. However they are not as easily accessible and no power cables are nearby.

[image: Bottom left is where I’m thinking it should go but the bay is too wide]

Comment: As you say, you either need the plastic "pinch" rails to fit it under the hard drive, or you have to fit it in the small bay under the DVD drive area.

Comment: As long as the SSD is not flapping around, its fine. Double sided velcro normally does the job.

Comment: @mt025 so attach below hard drive with the double sided velcro? Won’t get too hot?

Comment: I would attach it to the base. The ssd itself shouldn't get very hot.

Comment: Thanks @mt025 - so even ok to attach with the large flat surface against the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell and other companies who ship fully built computers generally don't provide the parts to easily add extra drives yourself (as in this case you are missing the drive 'rails' they use to easily insert a drive and this is why your kit doesn't 'fit').

However SSD's are very versatile and so you can mount them in a number of 'non-traditional' ways. In a case where you're *sure* it won't accidently get moved, you can simply lie the SSD in the correct place and leave it there, as they are so light the cables will hold it in the correct positon unless you've moved the PC or something (and in which case you should be checking everything inside anyway).

Also you can use double sided sticky tape, or velco backed tape to more securely attach it in a particular area.

You can mount it where ever you'd like as long as the cables fit, but in my experience the cables from cases such as this will only just fit to the 'normal' location, not giving you much choice. Just make sure not to block any air vents.

Comment: Thanks - I think I’ll use double sided Velcro. Would it be ok (ie no problems with it getting too hot) to literally attach it laying down - so flat against the inside casing somewhere?

Comment: *"...generally don't provide the parts to easily add extra drives yourself"* -- The various Dell & HP PCs that I've seen all had spare rails and screws to add additional drives.

Comment: @sawdust ok - My info is 2-5 years out of date I guess, depending on which machines I was working on, and only ever machines destined for business use, not home users -- is this the difference?